# "The shoemaker's son goes barefoot" en français

Tags: anglais, expressions

Comment puis-je dire *the shoemaker's son goes barefoot*. Cette expression s'emploie lorsqu'une personne dans une famille a quelque compétence spéciale, mais que sa famille ne se bénéficie pas de cette compétence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En français on appelle ça:

> Le syndrôme du cordonnier mal chaussé.

Mais ta phrase signifie littéralement:

> Le fils du cordonnier est nu-pieds

Ce proverbe s'applique à tout ceux qui ont une compétence quelconque qui ne l'appliquent pas à eux-mêmes.
Quelques exemples: un dentiste qui à des caries, ou bien un nutritionniste avec un surplus de poids.

Comment: Ne pas l'appliquer à soi-même et ne pas l'appliquer à sa famille c'est quand même différent.

Comment: Dans un certain sens vous avez raison, d'un autre côté, pour la famille directe, j'emploierais quand même l'expression. J'imagine mal un parent dentiste avoir un enfant qui ne prends pas soins de ses dents.

Comment: L'explication n'est pas mauvaise mais il manque le principal : comment évoque-t-on en français ce paradoxe bien connu ? Par quelle(s) formule(s) ?

Comment: Ici au Quebec, nous appelons ça "Le syndrôme du cordonnier mal chaussé"

Answer (score 4):

« [Les cordonniers sont toujours les plus mal chaussés](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/les_cordonniers_sont_toujours_les_plus_mal_chauss%C3%A9s) » est l'expression la plus proche qui correspond en français. On retrouve tous les ingrédients excepté celui de la famille, qui est rarement important. En ce sens, elle se rapproche un peu plus des quelques variantes qui existent [en anglais](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/159008) ou dans [d'autres langues](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/159040) et qui s'appliquent directement à la maison du plombier ou du forgeron.
 Les anglo-saxons et les allemands introduisent la famille du cordonnier, Rabelais exprimait la même idée du médecin qui soigne les autres mais est « d'ulcères tout infect », ([image venue de la Bible](http://saintebible.com/luke/4-23.htm)), pour les espagnols le forgeron mange avec des cuillères en bois, en arabe c'est le potier qui sert l'eau dans une cruche cassée, dans tous les cas on est dans l'équivalence tant du point de vue du niveau de langue que de la référence culturelle.

Comment: Réponse initiée par [Laure](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/358/laure) par ses commentaires.

Comment: Et j'en ai un peu rajouté... j'ai rappelé Rabelais et la Bible, cette dernière étant une référence quasi universelle. Et aussi tout le monde ne comprend pas l'anglais. (Ce n'est pas le cas du PO, bien sûr).

Answer (score 2):

Peut-être peut-on traduire cette expression avec quelque chose du genre:

> Il n'a pas hérité du don de son père pour la cordonnerie.

Le père peut évidemment être remplacé par n'importe quel membre de la famille, et le métier par n'importe quelle activité. Un don étant dans ce cas une aptitude innée pour quelque chose.

> Il n'a pas hérité du don de son frère pour le football.

On peut dire aussi

> La famille n'a pas hérité du don de l'oncle Sam pour les sports de ballon.